# Adding a method to onselectionchanged property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am Adding a calendar control to a view. I am using MVC project.

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Cal" runat="server"
            onselectionchanged="C_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>
        <br />
```

Now, where should i declare the `C_SelectionChanged` method, When the user selects a date from the `Calendar` this method should get executed. Can someone tell me where and how to add this method ?

Answer (score 0):

In a normal ASP.NET website you should set AutoPostBack="true"

webform.apsx

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Cal" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" 
         onselectionchanged="CalSelectionChanged" />
```

and then add the method that the event will call

webform.aspx.cs

```
protected void CalSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //do some stuff
}
```

But in MVC it is all another story because you don't have postback, viewstate.
Normal server control are quite useless because they relay on them.

To implement a calendar in MVC try the [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

[There you can find a complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329849/asp-net-calendar-onselectionchanged-handler-not-getting-called)

Comment: But i don't have a `aspx.cs` files. It's a MVC application. In the `View` i only have `.aspx` files. and in the `controller` and `model` folder that contains some `.cs` files. So where should i add the above function ?

Comment: @user1315906 I added an example

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your C_SelectionChanged event on aspx page for this you have to code like this:

```
<script runat="server">
void C_SelectionChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code here
}
</script>
```